# Transactions stuck in pending state on a geth node

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, nodes, pending-transactions

I have a private network of a geth and a few parity nodes. I use the geth node to submit transactions via RPC. A mining pool runs on one of the parity nodes. That node is connected to the geth node using the `--reserved-peers` flag.

I'm sending identical transactions in batches of 300. The first few batches were processed, but then about 1000 transactions stuck in the pending state. The mining pool continued generating empty blocks, the geth node indicated that it was connected to the other nodes, but the transactions were there for a few days. BTW I checked the nonce -- the sequence was OK.

```
> txpool.status
{
  pending: 1115,
  queued: 0
}
```

Today I restarted the geth node, and a portion of the pending transactions (2 blocks) was mined right away. And now nothing again. There is this suspicious message:

```
WARN [01-14|10:30:16.650] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=8aae420436ab0d4c err="action from bad peer ignored"
```

But running `admin.peers` tells me that the node with the mining pool is still connected (it has a different ID).

How do I make the geth node submit all pending transactions without having to restart it all the time?

Comment: Are they from the same sender? Are the tx nonces in sequencial order? We've done similar test in the past and the problem was that after some time transactions were dropped from the pending transactions (out guess is that we reached some internal limit of geth) then the missing nonces caused following transaction to get stuck.

Comment: Yes, the transactions are identical. And I checked the nonce -- it was OK. The fact that a portion of transactions was mined immediately after a restart implies that the transactions were good, there was something with the node. Actually, another portion (81 transactions, a single block) has been mined since I wrote this question, although it's been 20 hours and many empty blocks.